Perforce error "SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading" when submitting
I wanted to use a Perforce depot after some time of inactivity but I couldn't connect to the server anymore (hosted on a remote OVH server). To have it online again, I battled for a day, updating everything on the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server, and having issues with conflicting config files (I don't really know why I had conflicts all of a sudden).
I don't know much about Linux as it's my first forray into server stuff and I set it up a couple years ago. Anyway, after some hours of debugging, having only one P4 config file (in etc/perforce/p4dctl.conf), then resetting the P4SSLDIR stuff (I think the first problem was simply a certificate issue but there's no sure way to know it now), I managed to get my depot back and running. Using P4V, I can access the different workspaces and check out files.
After some time, I wanted to submit a change but I realized that I can't, as submitting would disconnect me from the server. The P4V error was not really understanble so I went for a command line p4 submit and got this error :
SSL receive failed.
read: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading: LÆopÚration a rÚussi.
Perforce client error:
        SSL receive failed.
        read: error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading: LÆopÚration a rÚussi.

(The LÆopÚration a rÚussi part is French for operation successful)
After a few hours searching for this issue around the interwebs, I could only find errors related to OpenSSL for the unexpected eof while reading but it seemed to be related to Ubuntu 22.04 and not 20.04.
I tried to do stuff I found here and there, mostly updating packages, and I ended up updating the OS to 22.04 then updating everything once again.
No luck there, whatever I do, I can't manage to submit on any of my workspaces (but I can still update and check-out), nor can I create a new workspace (I get the same error).
Is there something obvious I'm missing ?
Does anyone have any advice on debugging strategies ?
Thank you for your time.

Well, someone commented here talking about being about to reahc Helix' support but they deleted their post instead of giving progress, so I guess I will send Helix an email at some point, since no one else seems to have had this issue :(

Alright, it's fixed. I've asked a friend to try to submit and it worked for them. I though maybe it had something to do with the language of Windows but it still didn't work after I switched it to English (US).
Anyway, I updated the helix package on the server and now, it works so... thanks Perforce staff, I guess.
